# ExpressJS redirect giving net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR error in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ssl, browser

I've got a simple URL shortener set up with an express server. The idea is that when you submit a URL via the form, express will redirect you to an extension that serves a dynamic page (created with a template string) displaying the full shortened URL to copy and share. Everything works as expected in Postman but in browsers I get this error in the console:
`GET https://localhost:5000/view/2vfJqm net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

The `https://localhost:5000/view/2vfJqm` url is the endpoint express is redirecting to that serves the dynamic page.

So, I know there is an SSL problem here. My server is not set up to work on https and Chrome/firefox automatically try to make the link https which breaks it. When I copy that link into the address bar and change `https` to `http` I get the page served as expected. I've tried setting up the server with https using the `https` module in node and creating a self-signed certificate, adding it to the trusted cert list (this is on MacOS 10.14 Mojave), but I can't seem to get Chrome to recognize the cert even exists. I get the "Back to safety" warning page from chrome. Now, I'm like 99% sure that this is where the problem is. I just can't figure out how to make it work.

It's also possible I'm using Express' `redirect` method incorrectly. But the fact that it works as expected in Postman leads me to believe the problem is in the browser and not the code.

Is there a way to do this without https and the SSL cert? I'm just trying to get the thing up and running at this point and it seems silly to require all these extra steps for this basic functionality on a local server and for it to not be mentioned anywhere in the Express docs.

This is the problem endpoint:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import * as urls from '../models/url';

type controller = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void;

export const addUrl: controller = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { url } = req.body;
  const fullHash = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(url).digest('base64');
  // replaces url-breaking characters '+', '/', '=', '$'
  const urlSafe = fullHash
    .replace(/\+/g, '-')
    .replace(/\//g, '_')
    .replace(/=+$/g, '');
  // truncate hash into 6 character string
  const hash = urlSafe.substring(0, 6);
  const args = { hash, url };

  try {
    // check if url already exists in db
    const url = await urls.getUrl(hash);
    if (!url) {
      try {
        await urls.addUrl(args);
      } catch (e) {
        next(e);
      }
    }

    res.redirect(`/view/${hash}`);
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
};
```

That redirect hits this endpoint:

```
router.get('/view/:hash', (req, res) => {
  const view = submittedView(req.params.hash);
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html').status(200).send(view);
});
```

And `submittedView()` is just a function that returns a template string with the html.

I'd appreciate any help. Let me know if missed any important info.

Comment: While this ain't an answer yet (need to understand the context more), why do you have HTTPS for localhost? Could that be any kickstarter for your concern?

Comment: @SatyaKalluri I've never run into this problem before, but I've also never used a redirect before. HTTPS appears to be necessary for that operation because all modern browsers seem to be enforcing HTTPS even on localhost. So, while I can type `http://localhost:5000/whatever` into the address bar and get the correct response from my server, if I hit a redirect, the browser will automatically switch to https and error out regardless of the redirect's explicit url. The only way I found to get around that was to make the server https.

Comment: @SatyaKalluri I was able to fix the original issue by properly authorizing my SSL cert. I had to change settings to "always trust" my self-signed cert.